# What is the neuroscientific difference between learning/memorizing and understanding in the brain?

Tags: neuroscience, learning, memory, brain

I'm trying to understand how our brains - neurons or other chemical processes work in regards to learning/ memorizing and understanding.

I found a lot of "theoretical" discussions on the topic- e.g. learning is memorizing, and understanding is knowing how to apply something. But none of them talked about the actual process in the brain.

Comment: Do you mean the cognitive aspect of the process, or the neuro aspect?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking. I meant the physical aspect of it- neurons/ chemicals/ etc.

Comment: it's because there are two different (but related!) fields that both attempt to answer your question: cognitive psychology and neuroscience. I want to be clear which framework you would like to use

Comment: Ahh I see. Honestly I'm not too familiar with either, so I wouldn't be able to tell you. If you know any of them (or both) that will be great and we can go from there.

Comment: The best way to for you is to learn both subjects. If you have time take a look at some textbooks. Those are interesting

Answer (score 1):

According to [this fascinating chapter](https://pc.cogs.indiana.edu/2016/02/learning-as-coordination/), learning, memorization, and understanding are all related.

You might want to check it out. It basically   assumes learning to be a process that involves coordination of the various cognitive sub-processes.